# get the value of an attribute with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html, generated with JS.

```
  <div lang="en" id="s7_videoview_playPauseButton" class="s7playpausebutton" data-description="Scene7ComponentHolder" data-component="PlayPauseButton" state="up" selected="true"></div>
```

I want to grab the value of the selected attribute when this button is clicked, I'm using this code:

```
$(document).on('click ', '.s7playpausebutton', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).attr('selected'))
    $(this).val($(this).attr("selected"));
});
```

but it always gives me back "selected" and not the actual value ie. true or false. What is wrong?

Comment: Neither `selected` or `state` are valid attributes on a `div` element. Change them both to `data` attributes too.

Comment: Use a `data-*` attribute.... also `$(this).text( $(this).attr("selected") );`

Comment: Problem it's third party code, and that's the attribute that is added.

Comment: There should be no space in `click `

Comment: Whats the third party plugin? I don't think you are going to be able to get the attribute as it might be that selected has special semantics in HTML. You could use plain JS which would work: `console.log(e.target.getAttribute('selected'));`

Comment: it's not a button its a div

Comment: it's scene7 html videoviewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's useful to note that the selected attribute is traditionally unique to `<option>` elements, not `<div>` elements. This causes issues with jquery's `$().attr()` method. However, good old javascript works as expected.
Replacing

```
$(this).val($(this).attr("selected"));
```

with

```
this.getAttribute('selected');
```

should fix your issue.

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mnyzs/x3nvmpmf/1/) as well.